# Proc Sql doesn’t execute the 'order by' line when creating a new table in Teradata

Tags: sql, sas, teradata, proc

I'm trying to use SAS (via SAS EG 4.3) to create a new table in Teradata from an existing sas dataset. The existing sas data set is sorted as needed.

The code will run ok with no errors, and a new table is created in Teradata but it does not execute the order by line in the code . If I set the trace option and look in the sas log the 'orderby ..' line doesn't show in the trace.

The TD table is not ordered as needed , any ideas ?

Regards

sas code

```
%include "$HOME/tdpp_5200.sas";

options SASTRACE=',,,d' SASTRACELOC=SASLOG MLOGIC MPRINT;

%let Teradata_db = U_DOATDB; 

%let Teradata_tb = TBL_AS2_AUDIT_AGG_18MTH;

%let primary_key = 'primary index(CAT)';

libname tdata &rdbms &dbc_info database=&Teradata_db.;

libname datalib "/wload/ar3p/gpfs/teamproj/intr/Projects/AS2_CONTROL_RPT/";

proc sql;

create table tdata.&Teradata_tb. (FASTLOAD=yes dbcreate_table_opts=   primary_key) as 

select * from datalib.tbl_AS2_audit_agg_18mth

order by AS_YEAR, AS2_MONTH, EVENT_TYPE, RESULT_TYPE,REASON_TYPE,  OPERATOR_TYPE;

Quit;

libname tdata clear;

libname datalib clear;
```

SAS Log

```
  0 1475134126 trprep 0 SQL (2) 
TERADATA_0: Prepared: on connection 1 1 1475134126 trprep 0 SQL (2) 
SELECT * FROM U_DOATDB."TBL_AS2_AUDIT_AGG_18MTH" 2 1475134126 trprep 0 SQL (2) 
  3 1475134126 trprep 0 SQL (2) 

TERADATA: trforc: COMMIT WORK  4 1475134126 trforc 0 SQL (2) 
NOTE: SAS variable labels, formats, and lengths are not written to DBMS tables.
  5 1475134132 trexec 0 SQL (2) 

TERADATA_1: Executed: on connection 2 6 1475134132 trexec 0 SQL (2) 

CREATE MULTISET TABLE U_DOATDB."TBL_AS2_AUDIT_AGG_18MTH" ("CAT" CHAR (200),"AS_Year" DECIMAL(11),"As2_Month" 
DECIMAL(11),"EVENT_TYPE" INTEGER,"RESULT_TYPE" CHAR (1),"REASON_TYPE" INTEGER,"OPERATOR_TYPE" CHAR (8),"VOL" FLOAT) primary 
index(CAT);COMMIT WORK 7 1475134132 trexec 0 SQL (2) 
  8 1475134132 trexec 0 SQL (2)
```

Comment: A table in Teradata is never ordered in any visible way, internally it's sorted by a hash value.

Comment: Hi dnoeth, Thanks for the prompt reply . So it would seem that adding an order by clause is a waste and not needed. Is there any reason as to why the line was excluded from the SQL passed to Teradata ?

Comment: As you say.. It isn't needed.  The libname engine converts  the SAS SQL into 'native sql' as part of the pass-through conversion process.

Comment: @R.Slater: You should be glad is was removed, otherwise the Insert will fail.

Comment: @dnoeth Sounds like you should post an answer!

Answer (score 1):

Teradata does not support ordering of data in tables, so SAS removed the `ORDER BY` clause when passing the code to Teradata. Otherwise the code would have failed.

When reading the data back into SAS you can use any variables you want on a BY statement and SAS will tell Teradata to order the data on the way out of the table.

```
proc print data=datalib.tbl_AS2_audit_agg_18mth;
  by AS_YEAR AS2_MONTH EVENT_TYPE RESULT_TYPE REASON_TYPE OPERATOR_TYPE;
run;
```